# Pivot to Center Of Mass/Volume in pie menu error

Tags: python, pie-menu

I have the *Pivot to Center Of Mass* and *Pivot to Center Of Volume* functions inside a pie menu:

```
import bpy
from bpy.types import Menu, Operator


class RP_MT_TransformEdits(Menu):
    # bl_label is displayed at the center of the pie menu
    bl_label = 'Transform Edits'
    bl_idname = 'RP_MT_TransformEdits'


    def draw(self, context):
        layout = self.layout
        pie = layout.menu_pie()
        # Here should be every function for the pie menu
        # Order the lines in different order for different pie order
        # Pie order: west, east, south, north, north-west, north-east, south-west, south-east
        pie.operator('object.center_of_mass', icon = 'SNAP_VOLUME')
        pie.operator('object.center_of_volume', icon = 'OUTLINER_OB_SURFACE')



class OT_PivotToCenterOfMass(Operator):
    #needs to be lower case and underscores as word separation
    bl_idname = 'object.center_of_mass'
    bl_label = 'Pivot to Center Of Mass'
    bl_description = "Set the object's origin, by either moving the data, or set to center of data, or use 3D cursor."

    def execute(self, context):
        bpy.ops.object.origin_set(type = 'ORIGIN_CENTER_OF_MASS', center = 'MEDIAN')
        return {'FINISHED'}



class OT_PivotToCenterOfVolume(Operator):
    #needs to be lower case and underscores as word separation
    bl_idname = 'object.center_of_volume'
    bl_label = 'Pivot to Center Of Volume'
    bl_description = "Set the object's origin, by either moving the data, or set to center of data, or use 3D cursor."

    def execute(self, context):
        bpy.ops.object.origin_set(type = 'ORIGIN_CENTER_OF_VOLUME', center = 'MEDIAN')
        return {'FINISHED'}



classes = (RP_MT_TransformEdits,
           OT_PivotToCenterOfMass,
           OT_PivotToCenterOfVolume,
           )


def register():
    for cls in classes:
        bpy.utils.register_class(cls)


def unregister():
    for cls in classes:
        bpy.utils.unregister_class(cls)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    register()
    bpy.ops.wm.call_menu_pie(name = 'RP_MT_TransformEdits')
```

When I try to use one of the functions I get the following error:

```
Error: Python: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "\Text", line 46, in execute
  File "C:\Program Files\Blender Foundation\Blender 3.0\3.0\scripts\modules\bpy\ops.py", line 132, in __call__
    ret = _op_call(self.idname_py(), None, kw)
TypeError: Converting py args to operator properties: : keyword "type" unrecognized
```

But running either

```
bpy.ops.object.origin_set(type = 'ORIGIN_CENTER_OF_MASS', center = 'MEDIAN')
```

or

```
bpy.ops.object.origin_set(type = 'ORIGIN_CENTER_OF_VOLUME', center = 'MEDIAN')
```

from the text editor works fine.
Why do I get this error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changing the id_name for each class to something unique instead of having the same as the operators in Blender fixes it:

```
import bpy
from bpy.types import Menu, Operator


class RP_MT_TransformEdits(Menu):
    # bl_label is displayed at the center of the pie menu
    bl_label = 'Transform Edits'
    bl_idname = 'RP_MT_TransformEdits'


    def draw(self, context):
        layout = self.layout
        pie = layout.menu_pie()
        # Here should be every function for the pie menu
        # Order the lines in different order for different pie order
        # Pie order: west, east, south, north, north-west, north-east, south-west, south-east
        pie.operator('test.pivot_to_center_of_mass', icon = 'SNAP_VOLUME')
        pie.operator('test.pivot_to_center_of_volume', icon = 'OUTLINER_OB_SURFACE')



class OT_PivotToCenterOfMass(Operator):
    #needs to be lower case and underscores as word separation
    bl_idname = 'test.pivot_to_center_of_mass'
    bl_label = 'Pivot to Center Of Mass'
    bl_description = "Set the object's origin, by either moving the data, or set to center of data, or use 3D cursor."

    def execute(self, context):
        bpy.ops.object.origin_set(type = 'ORIGIN_CENTER_OF_MASS', center = 'MEDIAN')
        return {'FINISHED'}



class OT_PivotToCenterOfVolume(Operator):
    #needs to be lower case and underscores as word separation
    bl_idname = 'test.pivot_to_center_of_volume'
    bl_label = 'Pivot to Center Of Volume'
    bl_description = "Set the object's origin, by either moving the data, or set to center of data, or use 3D cursor."

    def execute(self, context):
        bpy.ops.object.origin_set(type = 'ORIGIN_CENTER_OF_VOLUME', center = 'MEDIAN')
        return {'FINISHED'}



classes = (RP_MT_TransformEdits,
           OT_PivotToCenterOfMass,
           OT_PivotToCenterOfVolume,
           )


def register():
    for cls in classes:
        bpy.utils.register_class(cls)


def unregister():
    for cls in classes:
        bpy.utils.unregister_class(cls)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    register()
    bpy.ops.wm.call_menu_pie(name = 'RP_MT_TransformEdits')
```